# Choosing numbers at random from a set $\{0,1,2, \cdots 9\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We choose numbers at random from a set $\{0,1,2, \cdots 9\}$ (without replacement), four numbers a,b,c,d. What is the probability that:

a)a is the greatest value of those we have chosen

b) a,b,c,d is an ascending sequence

My question is first and foremost about the logic i.e. i want to know how to calculate those probabilities but i am much more interested why this is the probability we are looking for.
I know that for certain:
$$|\Omega|=10\times9\times8\times7$$

Comment: It is easier to make use of symmetry. We chose $4$ numbers one after the other. Whatever numbers we chose, the probability the first number chosen is biggest is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Ok but what about b)? I have also one more question about  par a if $|A|= $  $10 \choose 4$$\times 1\times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ what could be the logic behind such an answer i.e. how to justify it?

Comment: The same idea shows the answer to (b) is $\frac{1}{4!}$.

Comment: Ok, understand but what about my idea for an answer i wrote in a previous comment?

Comment: I have written out an answer that uses your sample space $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) We are choosing numbers one at a time. Whatever collection of numbers we chose, by symmetry the probability the first chosen number was biggest is $\frac{1}{4}$.

We can also make a calculation based on your sample space $\Omega$. As you pointed out, this sample space has $(10)(9)(8)(7)$ outcomes. We now count the *favourables*.

There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to choose a collection of $4$ numbers. For every such choice, there are $3!$ ways to arrange the numbers so that the biggest is first, for the others can be arranged in $3!$ ways. Thus the number of favourables is $\binom{10}{4}3!$.

Finally, for the probability, divide the number of favourables by $|\Omega|$. After some simplification, we get $\frac{1}{4}$. The simplicity of the answer strongly hints that there must be a nicer way.

b) The same symmetry argument shows that the probability our numbers are in increasing order is $\frac{1}{4!}$. For whatever numbers we chose, all $4!$ orderings are equally likely.

We can also work with the sample space $\Omega$. In this case, there are $\binom{10}{4}$ favourables.